# Dynamically selecting table using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a property name for different entities like car,person etc.Depending on the `Id` I want to get the name.But I would like to get it in done in a single method which takes entityName and gives the output depending on that.
  Something like this:

```
public string GetEntityByName(int id,string entityName)
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            return context[entityName].Find(id).Name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have some base entity class withe the `Name` property defined?

Comment: No there is no base entity class with Name property but it is common for many entities

Comment: How are you going to pass `entityName`, will it simply be the name of the `class` ("Car"), or the full `Type` name? Also, are all the requested Entities in the same namespace?

Answer (score 2):

All your entities should extend a base class or implement an interface that defines a `Name` property.

```
public interface INamed {
     string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Car : INamed {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not aware if `DbContext` supports indexed properties, but if it does, you may manage to do something like this:

```
INamed namedEntity = context[entityName].Find(id) as INamed;
if(namedEntity != null)
     return namedEntity.Name;
else
     return string.Empty;
```

If you're sure that all your entities are `INamed`, then you can achieve it all in one line:

```
return ((INamed)context[entityName].Find(id)).Name;
```

Please note that the latter approach will rise or throw an exception if the retrieved entity is not implementing `INamed`

Comment: yes my entities don't extend any base class or interface

Comment: @neelshah, So what do you expect will happen if the entity found doesn't contain the `Name` property?

Comment: return an empty string but it will always be there

Answer (score 2):

How about using generic method that indicates entity not by name but by type instead? The result you may store as dynamic variable so that you will be able to access any property in it.

```
public string GetEntityByName<TEntity>(int id)
{
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        dynamic entity = context.Set<TEntity>.Find(id);
        try
        {
            return entity.Name;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // Handle the situation when requested entity does not have Name property
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you may use reflection to access Name property:

```
public string GetEntityByName<TEntity>(int id)
{
    var nameProperty = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty("Name");
    if(nameProperty == null)
        return null;
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        object entity = context.Set<TEntity>.Find(id);
        return nameProperty.GetValue(entity) as string;
    }
}
```

The above methods you may use like that:

```
 string name = GetEntityByName<Car>(id);
```

If you insist on having the entity type passed as string parameter you may achieve it as well:

```
public string GetEntityByName(int id, string entityName)
{
    Type entityType = Type.GetType(entityName);
    var nameProperty = entityType.GetProperty("Name");
    if(nameProperty == null)
        return null;
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        object entity = context.Set(entityType).Find(id);
        return nameProperty.GetValue(entity) as string;
    }
}
```

The above works only if GetEntityByName method is defined in the same assembly and the same namespace as entity classes. Otherwise as parametr to GetType method you have to pass full type name.